# R Sum not returning correct value

Tags: r

I am new to R, and was playing with the quakes data, wonder to know how many quakes per mag:

```
quakes |> group_by(mag) |> mutate(count_per_mag=n())|> 
        select(-lat, -long, -depth,-stations)|> 
        unique()|> 
        arrange(mag)
```

The return table seems correct, as I know there are 1000 records,  then I'd like to count how many quakes happened, just to check it the value is 1000, then I used the following code:

```
quakes |> group_by(mag) |> 
       mutate(count_per_mag=n())|> 
       select(-lat, -long, -depth,-stations)|> 
       unique()|> arrange(mag) |> 
       mutate(total=sum(count_per_mag))
```

But the return total volumns are having the same value as the count_per_mag

Not sure why, can anyone explain to me why does this happen?

Comment: You're getting the same totals because you are adding only one number per group, after `unique` all groups have one element only. Try, `etc |> unique()|> group_size()` to see counts of 1.

Comment: So I need to ungroup first then get the total. Does this mean If I group_by xxx, the following operations are all based on each group? instead of the whole data set?

Comment: That depends on what you want. Try removing `unique` and see.

Comment: I would end the pipe with `summarise`, not `mutate`. Or maybe simply `quakes |> count(mag, name = "total")`?

Comment: If I remove the unique, multiple records with same mag level will be added up, since mutate(count_per_mag=n()) gets the total count for each mag, then the total number seems incorrect with duplicate counts added.

Comment: count(mag, name = "total") is a much smarter way to get the value for each mag, thanks for the tip.